# Skype: Not able to send file attachment to user

Tags: botframework, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

I am not able to send file attachment from a bot to a user in Skype. I am using bot builder version 3.5.0.

Below is my code.

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("blah");
reply.Attachments = new List();
Attachment attach = new Attachment();

attach.ContentType = "application/pdf";
// I can browse the below URL in browser and access the PDF
attach.ContentUrl = "https://test.azurewebsites.net/Image/Test.pdf";
attach.Name = "Test.pdf";
attach.Content = "Test";
attach.ThumbnailUrl = attach.ContentUrl;
reply.Attachments.Add(attach);
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: Apart from your problem of attachment: "BOT builder version 3.5.0" > you should use 3.9.0 or higher since July 2017 (https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/07/bot-framework-auth-change/)

Comment: After update the BOT builder version 3.5.0 to 4.0.8 still it's not working....Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the dire need to upgrade your version of botbuilder, there is also a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-SendAttachment) for this.  please refer to it for further guidance.  It is located in the [botbuilder-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repo. in the sample they are constructing the attachments very similar to how you are:

```
private static Attachment GetInternetAttachment()
{
    return new Attachment
    {
        Name = "BotFrameworkOverview.png",
        ContentType = "image/png",
        ContentUrl = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/media/how-it-works/architecture-resize.png"
    };
}
```

So this is most likely caused by the **very** outdated version of botbuilder you are using